# XSSFFont doesn't apply for all the cells Java POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

the XSSFFont object I used to apply Bold Font works for some cells and doesn't work for the rest of them.

Some cell is set to be bold in the code, but it is displayed as unbold in the excel file (the bold button is highlighted in the excel, but the cell is not bold) see image below

[bold font not wor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNtBN.png)

However, if I have few securities(like 40) under Unclassified (which is in the same level as Cash), the Cash is displayed in a bold format, as you see below. In The first picture, Unclassified has a lot of securities (520 ones)
see image below

[Bold font doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnFod.png)

my code is

```
private void writeCellToExcel(Workbook workBook, ExportExcelCell cell,

                 XSSFRow excelRow, int cellNumber, boolean isLastCell) {



          XSSFCell excelCell = (XSSFCell) excelRow.createCell(cellNumber);



          XSSFRichTextString cellValue = new XSSFRichTextString(cell.getText());



          XSSFCellStyle style = (XSSFCellStyle) workBook.createCellStyle();

          XSSFFont font = (XSSFFont) workBook.createFont();

          font.setFontName(ExportExcelConstants.EXPORT_EXCEL_DEFAULT_FONT_NAME);

          font.setFontHeight(ExportExcelConstants.EXPORT_EXCEL_DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE);



          applyCellStyleAndMerging(cell, cellNumber, isLastCell, excelCell,

                       cellValue, style, font);



          // sheet.autoSizeColumn(cellNumber);



   }



   private void applyCellStyleAndMerging(ExportExcelCell cell, int cellNumber,

                 boolean isLastCell, XSSFCell excelCell,

                 XSSFRichTextString cellValue, CellStyle style, XSSFFont font) {



          applyCellStyleAndData(cell, excelCell, cellNumber, cellValue, style,

                       font);



          int cellColSize = cell.getCellColSpan();

          int cellRowSize = cell.getCellRowSpan();

          // in case the cell might be more than one column or more than one

          // row

          if (cellColSize > 1 || cellRowSize > 1) {

                 applyCellMerging(cellNumber, isLastCell, cellColSize, cellRowSize);

          }



   }



   private void applyCellStyleAndData(ExportExcelCell cell,

                 XSSFCell excelCell, int cellNumber, XSSFRichTextString cellValue,

                 CellStyle style, XSSFFont font) {



          applyCellFontStyle(cell, cellValue, style, font);



          applyCellAlignmentIndentionAndValue(cell, excelCell, cellNumber,

                       cellValue, style);

   }



   private void applyCellFontStyle(ExportExcelCell cell,

                 XSSFRichTextString cellValue, CellStyle style, XSSFFont font) {



          String fontStyle = cell.getStyle();

          if (ExportExcelConstants.EXPORT_EXCEL_CELL_FONT_BOLD

                       .equalsIgnoreCase(fontStyle)) {

                 font.setBold(true);

                 style.setFont(font);

          } else if (ExportExcelConstants.EXPORT_EXCEL_CELL_FONT_SHEET_HEAD

                       .equalsIgnoreCase(fontStyle)) {

                 int colunindex = cell.getText().indexOf(":");

                 font.setBold(true);

                 cellValue.applyFont(0, colunindex, font);

          } else if (ExportExcelConstants.EXPORT_EXCEL_CELL_FONT_ITALIC

                       .equalsIgnoreCase(fontStyle)) {

                 font.setItalic(true);

                 style.setFont(font);

          } else if (ExportExcelConstants.EXPORT_EXCEL_CELL_FONT_UNDERLINE

                       .equalsIgnoreCase(fontStyle)) {

                 font.setUnderline(XSSFFont.U_SINGLE);

                 style.setFont(font);

          } else {

                 style.setFont(font);

          }



   }



   private void applyCellAlignmentIndentionAndValue(ExportExcelCell cell,

                 XSSFCell excelCell, int cellNumber, XSSFRichTextString cellValue,

                 CellStyle style) {

          String cellAlignment = cell.getCellAlignment();

          style.setAlignment(getCellAlignment(cellAlignment));

          style.setVerticalAlignment(ExportExcelConstants.EXPORT_EXCEL_DEFAULT_CELL_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT);

          excelCell.setCellValue(cellValue);

          excelCell.setCellStyle(style);

   }



   private void applyCellMerging(int cellNum, boolean isLastCell,

                 int cellColSize, int cellRowSize) {



          int firstrowMergedIndex = rowNumber + 1;

          int lastrowMergedIndex = 0;

          int cellMerged = cellNum;

          ArrayList<Integer> columnMerged = new ArrayList<Integer>();



          if (cellColSize > 1 && cellRowSize == 1) {

                 sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowNumber, rowNumber,

                              cellNum, cellNum + cellColSize - 1));



          } else if (cellColSize == 1 && cellRowSize > 1) {

                 sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowNumber, rowNumber

                              + cellRowSize - 1, cellNum, cellNum));



                 lastrowMergedIndex = rowNumber + cellRowSize - 1;



                 if (isLastCell) {

                       rowNumber = rowNumber + cellRowSize - 1;

                 }



                 columnMerged.add(cellNum);

                 while (firstrowMergedIndex <= lastrowMergedIndex) {

                       mergedRowsCells.put(firstrowMergedIndex, columnMerged);

                       firstrowMergedIndex++;

                 }



          } else {



                 sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowNumber, rowNumber

                              + cellRowSize - 1, cellNum, cellNum + cellColSize - 1));



                 lastrowMergedIndex = rowNumber + cellRowSize - 1;



                 if (isLastCell) {

                       rowNumber = rowNumber + cellRowSize - 1;

                 }



                 while (firstrowMergedIndex <= lastrowMergedIndex) {

                       while (cellMerged <= cellNum + cellColSize - 1) {

                              columnMerged.add(cellMerged);

                              cellMerged++;

                       }

                       mergedRowsCells.put(firstrowMergedIndex, columnMerged);

                       firstrowMergedIndex++;

                 }



          }



   }



   private Short getCellAlignment(String cellAlignment) {



          if (cellAlignment == null) {

                 return CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT;

          }



          Short alignment = null;

          switch (cellAlignment) {



          case "left":

                 alignment = CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT;

                 break;



          case "center":

                 alignment = CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION;

                 break;



          case "right":

                 alignment = CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT;

                 break;



          case "fill":

                 alignment = CellStyle.ALIGN_FILL;

                 break;



          case "default":

                 alignment = CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT;

                 break;



          }



          return alignment;



   }



   private int getFirstCellToWrite(XSSFRow excelRow, boolean isSubRow,

                 int nestedLevel) {

          if (!isSubRow) {



                 if (mergedRowsCells.containsKey(rowNumber)) {

                       ArrayList<Integer> mergedCells = mergedRowsCells.get(rowNumber);

                       return mergedCells.get(mergedCells.size() - 1) + 1;

                 }



                 return 0;

          }



          return nestedLevel;



   }
```

the domain object is

```
public class ExportExcelCell {



   @JsonProperty("text")

   private String text;



   @JsonProperty("style")

   private String style;



   @JsonProperty("cellRowSpan")

   private Integer cellRowSpan;



   @JsonProperty("cellColSpan")

   private Integer cellColSpan;



   @JsonProperty("cellAlignment")

   private String cellAlignment;



   public ExportExcelCell() {



   }



   public String getText() {

          return text;

   }



   public void setText(String text) {

          this.text = text;

   }



   public String getStyle() {

          return style;

   }



   public void setStyle(String style) {

          this.style = style;

   }



   public Integer getCellRowSpan() {

          return cellRowSpan;

   }



   public void setCellRowSpan(int cellRowSpan) {

          this.cellRowSpan = cellRowSpan;

   }



   public Integer getCellColSpan() {

          return cellColSpan;

   }



   public void setCellColSpan(int cellColSpan) {

          this.cellColSpan = cellColSpan;

   }



   public String getCellAlignment() {

          return cellAlignment;

   }



   public void setCellAlignment(String exportExcelDefaultCellAlignment) {

          this.cellAlignment = exportExcelDefaultCellAlignment;

   }



   @Override

   public String toString() {

          return "ExportExcelCell [text=" + text + ", style=" + style

                       + ", cellRowSpan=" + cellRowSpan + ", cellColSpan="

                       + cellColSpan + ", cellAlignment=" + cellAlignment + "]";

   }


}
```

Comment: I basically checked your code, as far as possible, cause u didnt provide the  constant class `ExportExcelConstants` and field `mergedRowsCells` However the code along setting the textformat seems to be correct. In my testcase i populate ~2500 rows of text with bold font, produced by your code.. anything worked fine. So i guess, it is not a problem with apache-poi. Guessing, because i had to mock some `ExportExcelCell` instances, and didnt know, if it is comparable to those instances you are using.I rather suggest, you debug your code carefully

Comment: Thanks for your comment, actually I found the cause of my problem which is  the maximum number of unique fonts ( font of each cell) in a workbook is limited to 32767, and since I have more than 32767 cells and I created a unique font for each one , the ones that exceed the 32767 doesn't get the right font